# Validate a HH:MM time

Tags: javascript, html

This is my javascript sample. How can it be improvised?

```
function a(id) 
{
    var n=document.getElementById(id);
    var re=/^[0-9]:[0-9] [to] [0-9]:[0-9]*$/;

    if(re.test(n.value))
    {
        n.style.backgroundColor="#52F40C";
    }
    else
    {
        window.alert("Invalid Entry");
        n.style.backgroundColor="#F40C0C";
        n.focus();
        n.value="";
    }
}
```

I wanna validate user input which should be for example 10:30 to 12:30. I'm a fresher please suggest me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this regex for time format hh:mm

```
^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$
```

I have just placed the time format.Try to edit this for your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I believe, this is what you're looking for:

```
^0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]:[0-5][0-9] to 0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]:[0-5][0-9]$
```

You can check it here: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ENz9p/)

Answer (score 2):

To check whether a string matches a **24h format** (range *00:00 → 23:59*)  use [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

```js
// Validate "hh:mm" format
const validHHMMstring = (str) => /^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/.test(str);

console.log(validHHMMstring("99:99")); // false
console.log(validHHMMstring("24:00")); // false
console.log(validHHMMstring("23:60")); // false
console.log(validHHMMstring("23:59")); // true
console.log(validHHMMstring("00:00")); // true
```

Use Like:

```js
// Having i.e: <input name="time">
const time = document.querySelector("[name=time]").value.trim();
if (validHHMMstring(time)) {
  // do something, is valid HH:MM
}
```