# How to validate time input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML text box () for input time that is in **hh:mm** format (h: hour and m: minute). I would like user to input the time in that format. How can I achieve that by using jQuery or some JavaScript codes?  Thank you.

Comment: You can use Regular Expressions in JavasScript for that.

Comment: You can use Google for that

Comment: Please post the [**current code**](http://whathaveyoutried.com) that you are having issues with so we can help you fix it. If possible could you also add a [**fiddle**](http://jsFiddle.net) (or similar) that demonstrates the issue which then as well can serve as a playground to test different solutions at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

There are many [jQuery plugins](http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/input-format) that do input formatting/validation. A tricky part might be to come up with a regular expression that validates correct times. This [example](https://www.debuggex.com/r/zhkkf7-GQegyTYOq) is pretty flexible:

```
^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

It allows the first `0` to be optional, and ensures that hours don't go above 23. It also makes sure that the minutes are between `00` and `59`.

---

Depending on how you parse your result, you might want to be more restrictive. For instance, you could remove the `?` from the regex to force HH:MM format, and still ensure that hours are between `00` and `23`, while minutes are between `00` and `59`. It looks like [that](https://www.debuggex.com/r/tBwwHH7azQQCMovy):

```
^([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex to validate time in hh:mm format.

```
^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$
```

You might have to edit for your specific use case.

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ENz9p/27/

source: [How to validate a time user input like hh:mm to hh:mm in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472660/how-to-validate-a-time-user-input-like-hhmm-to-hhmm-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do it in js (Date.parse), but I think moment.js is the easiest (most robust) way out there.

http://momentjs.com/

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I am newbie with javascript.

Comment: I thought that momentjs was for time formatting/parsing, rather than input validation? My understanding is that the OP wants to ensure the users are inputing in the right format.