# Check the value of the field in HH:MM format using ajax javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a field *HrsBirthDate* which should take input in format HH:MM (it can be 00:01, 01:19, 23:44, 19:34, 13:12).

So before submitting the form I need to check whether the value is in any of the above formats else throw an error message.

Now only I can check that the field is not empty.

This is my code:

```
        $("body").on("click", "#WebGrid TBODY .Update", function () {
           var row = $(this).closest("tr");
           var employee = {};
           employee.EmployeeID = row.find(".EmployeeId").find(".label").html();
           employee.FirstName = row.find(".Name").find(".text").val();
           employee.BirthDate = row.find(".DOB").find(".text").val();
           employee.HrsBirthDate = row.find(".HrsBirthDate").find(".text").val();
 
           if (employee.FirstName != '' && employee.BirthDate != '' && employee.HrsBirthDate != '') {
               debugger;
               $("td", row).each(function () {
                   if ($(this).find(".text").length > 0) {
                       var span = $(this).find(".label");
                       var input = $(this).find(".text");
                       span.html(input.val());
                       span.show();
                       input.hide();
                   }
               });
               row.find(".Edit").show();
               row.find(".Cancel").hide();
               $(this).hide();
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "/Home/UpdateEmployee",
                   data: '{employee:' + JSON.stringify(employee) + '}',
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   dataType: "json"
               });
           }
           else {
               alert("Please fill the details.");
               return false;
           }
       });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether a string matches a **24h format** (*hh:mm* range *00:00 → 23:59*) we can use a small **regular expression** with [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

```js
const validHHMMstring = (str) => /^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/.test(str);

console.log(validHHMMstring("99:99")); // false
console.log(validHHMMstring("24:00")); // false
console.log(validHHMMstring("23:60")); // false
console.log(validHHMMstring("23:59")); // true
console.log(validHHMMstring("00:00")); // true
```

and use it like:

```js
if (validHHMMstring(employee.HrsBirthDate)) {
  // do something, is valid HH:MM
}
```

Comment: How could you think this is *not* a duplicate many times over?

Comment: @HereticMonkey the only dupe I could quickly find was [this dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14472703/383904) - and the accepted answer is not even correct. Neither is correct the answer in [this dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5563222/383904)

Comment: Then add a correct answer to the duplicate of your choice, and try to convince the asker that yours is correct. Or not, a duplicate's accepted answer does not need to be correct to be a duplicate target.